# How to print the duplicates in a linked list with number of occurences?

Tags: c, linked-list, format, ip, counter

I am trying to count the occurrences of the IP in the linked list and print out the count for each individual ip address. I am able to print the count but when I iterate it the count decreases and duplicates are printed. Also, they should be sorted with highest login count at the top.

I have tried implementing this using an array by creating copies into the array for each IP but that is not effective because the size of the array cannot be determined before hand for each user.

Expected output:

```
    IP Address Count
    --------------------
    97.88.145.98 12
    141.219.153.201 4
    141.219.209.223 3
    141.219.210.114 3
    141.219.208.123 1
    75.129.96.98 1
    141.219.210.180 1
```

Current Output:

```
  IP Address    Occurence
---------------------------
    141.219.153.201     4
    141.219.153.201     3
    97.88.145.98        12
    97.88.145.98        11
    97.88.145.98        10
    97.88.145.98        9
    97.88.145.98        8
    141.219.210.114     3
    141.219.210.114     2
    141.219.210.114     1
    97.88.145.98        7
    97.88.145.98        6
    141.219.210.180     1
    97.88.145.98        5
    97.88.145.98        4
    97.88.145.98        3
    97.88.145.98        2
    75.129.96.98        1
    141.219.209.223     3
    141.219.209.223     2
    141.219.209.223     1
    97.88.145.98        1
    141.219.153.201     2
    141.219.208.123     1
    141.219.153.201     1
```

Function to iterate the linked list.

```
bstNode* search(char* key, bstNode* root)
{
    int res;
    bstNode *leaf = root;

    if( leaf != NULL ) {
        res = strcmp(key, leaf->data);
        if( res < 0)
            search( key, leaf->left);
        else if( res > 0)
            search( key, leaf->right);
        else
        {
            printf("\n'%s' found!\n", key);
            printf("---------------------------\n  IP Address\tOccurence\n---------------------------\n");
            //int count = 0;
            IP *temp = leaf->ipHead;

            while (temp) {

                int tempip = temp->ip;
                int ipcount = 0;



                uint32_t ip = tempip;
                struct in_addr ip_addr;
                ip_addr.s_addr = ip;

                //bstNode *cpy = leaf;

                ipcount = count(temp, tempip);
                //temp->count = ipcount;

                //temp = leaf;

                //printf("The IP address is %s\n C:%d\n", inet_ntoa(ip_addr), ipcount);
                printf("    %s\t\t%i\n", inet_ntoa(ip_addr), ipcount);
                temp = temp->ipNext;
            }
        }
    }

    else printf("\nNot in tree\n");
    return leaf;
}
```

Function to count the occurences:

```
 int count(IP* start, int item)
    {
        IP* current = start;

        int c = 0;
        while (current)
        {
            if (current->ip == item)
            {
                c++;
            }
            current = current->ipNext;
        }
        //printf("Count is: %d", c);
        return c;
    }
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: I strongly advise you (a) keep the list of IPs in each BST node sorted (easy to do on insert). Then, (b) add a `count` member to the IP structure. When you take in a new IP to "add", look for it in the list. If you find it, just bump the count and don't add a new node. If you don't find it, insert the node wherever in the list it belongs with an count of `1`. In the end, you won't have any actual duplicates in the linked lists, but you *will* have distinct elements and their count of occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

There's no any conditional statements which filter duplicated IPs in the function search(), more precisely near 'while (temp)' loop.

count() just count in the list. and there's condition which select only the ip which match with argument.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is counting the number of occurrences of ip in the rest of the list.
So When your ip-list `temp` looks like

```
    ( ip1, ip2, ip1, ip2 )
```

then the loop iterates

```
    count( ip1, ( ip1, ip2, ip1, ip2 )); // => "ip1 2"
    count( ip2, ( ip2, ip1, ip2 ));      // => "ip2 2" 
    count( ip1, ( ip1, ip2 ));           // => "ip1 1"
    count( ip2, ( ip2 ));                // => "ip2 1"
```

To fix this, you must keep track of each ip for its being already counted:
Wrong:

```
    ipcount = count(temp, tempip);
    printf(...);
```

Right:

```
    if ( ! is_counted(tempip, memory_buffer_of_is_counted_bookkeeping) ) {
        ipcount = count(temp, tempip);
        printf(...);
        set_counted(tempip, memory_buffer_of_is_counted_bookkeeping);
    }
```

Of course the bookkeeping data must be emptied first.